Should MikroORM be injected into a builder class or should it be integrated into a repository for the same service?
I have a builder class which I simplified below:
interface Builder {
    setTitle(title: string): BookBuilder;
    ... // sets a bunch of attributes here
    build(): Book;
}
class BookBuilder implements Builder {
    declare private book: Book;
    
    constructor() {
        this.reset();
    }

    public reset(): void {
        this.book = new Book();
    }

    public setTitle(title: string): BookBuilder {
        this.book.title = title;
        return this;
    }

    ...

    public build(): Book {
        const result = this.book;
        this.reset();
        return result;
    }
}

This builder class allowed me to simplify the creation of books which will be important for the API. My question however, is when I want to commit these books to the database using MikroORM, I have to init MikroORM and use a forked entity manager. System design is something very new to me, although I  understand the usefulness in some patterns that I'm reading about.
I tried to inject the entity manager into the builder class but that didn't work. Now I'm attempting to create repository class in order to handle the books CRUD operations rather than having the builder handle everything. How would you guys approach this?
